# HTTP/2 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, h2, http2, alpn

I would like to try HTTP/2 on this site: https://www.alebalweb-blog.com/

I recently updated the server to Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7.2, Apache/2.4.29, etc,etc

I did: sudo a2enmod http2

Added:

```
#HTTP/2
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

In my VirtualHost SSL.

and restarted Apache.

The SSL certificate is provided by Let's Encrypt.

The result is:

```
curl -k -v --http2 https://alebalweb-blog.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://alebalweb-blog.com/
*   Trying 45.76.70.142...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to alebalweb-blog.com (45.76.70.142) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=alebalweb-blog.com
*  start date: Jul  7 02:02:06 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  5 02:02:06 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: alebalweb-blog.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 21:51:22 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< Upgrade: h2,h2c
< Connection: Upgrade
< Cache-Control: max-age=300
< Expires: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 21:56:22 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Really strange I think is this:

```
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
```

What does it mean?

HTTP/2 Test says:

```
HTTP/2 Test Result www.alebalweb-blog.com
Negative! www.alebalweb-blog.com does not support HTTP/2.0.
ALPN is not supported.
```

I feel like I missed something big... can you help me understand what?

Comment: The key is `* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1` which means that the server isn't advertising h2 support.

Comment: Which is weird as it supports ALPN and modern ciphers (so clearly a modern version of OpenSSL which is often a problem here) and the Upgrade header is being sent (which shows mod_http2 is set up correctly). I would guess you have something sitting in front of Apache (Nginx a load balancer a CDN) which does not support HTTP/2.

Comment: Is a Vultr server, Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded to 18.04, I ask Vultr if there is something that does not allow HTTP/2 to work.

Comment: Vultr responded to me to go look in the Docs section, and in the Docs section there is nothing that regards HTTP/2 and Apache... not much help... Can you help me figure out where I can look?

Comment: Does it work if connected directly to the server and doing `curl -k -v —http2 https://localhost`?

Comment: curl -k -v —http2 https://localhost? –
* Rebuilt URL to: —http2/
* Failed to convert —http2 to ACE; string contains a disallowed character

* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Failed to convert —http2 to ACE; string contains a disallowed character

* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost/?
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1  HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: The problem may be that I don't have a site in www (my root server)? I have www and inside www, www/site1, www/site2, www/site3, etc, on www there is no site.
000-default. conf is currently enabled (but I can disable it) and does not have an SSL certificate, it shows the main page of Apache. The "curl -k -v —http2 https://localhost? –" command shows the first site in my www folder. Looking for a solution I saw someone talk about PHP-fpm and Prefork, I don't have it, I installed PHP 7.2 not fpm, can be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved by switching to PHP-FPM

I used these codes:

```
apachectl stop
apt-get install php7.1-fpm # Install the php-fpm from your PHP repository. This package name depends on the vendor.
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.1-fpm # Again, this depends on your PHP vendor.
a2dismod php7.1 # This disables mod_php.
a2dismod mpm_prefork # This disables the prefork MPM. Only one MPM can run at a time.
a2enmod mpm_event # Enable event MPM. You could also enable mpm_worker.
apachectl start
```

from this guide: https://http2.pro/doc/Apache
and this guide: https://techwombat.com/enable-http2-apache-ubuntu-16-04/

and added "Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1" at the end of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Now the command curl -k -v --http2 https://alebalweb-blog.com reports this:

```
curl -k -v --http2 https://alebalweb-blog.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://alebalweb-blog.com/
*   Trying 45.76.70.142...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to alebalweb-blog.com (45.76.70.142) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=alebalweb-blog.com
*  start date: Jul  7 02:02:06 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Oct  5 02:02:06 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x556ec5957940)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: alebalweb-blog.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 20:21:38 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu)
< cache-control: max-age=300
< expires: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 20:26:38 GMT
< vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Above all you notice this changes: ALPN, server accepted to use h2, and HTTP/2 200

The site https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test, says:

```
Yeah! www.alebalweb-blog.com supports HTTP/2.0. 
ALPN supported.
```

And the development tools of opera and chrome indicate: h2

I only have one last doubt, in Google Webmaster tools, fetching the page as Google, I see this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 20:35:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu)
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Expires: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 20:40:35 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 41422
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

I missing something? Or maybe need time?